# what triggers assigning IPv6 link-local address in Android

Tags: android, ipv6

When joining into IPv6-only standalone network my Android device is not generating link-local IPv6 address (fe::) for Wifi interface but if I connect my router into outside gateway supporting IPv6, then link-local IPv6 address is generated.

Also if I enable IPv4 in the device then IPv6 link-local address is also generated.

Would anybody be able to explain me what Android device is actually expending in order to generate the link-local address? To my understanding, the link-local address should always be there no matter what when the link is up.

Comment: Hi Mikko, It's not good practise to add answers in the question text. I've moved it to a real answer

Comment: @Mikko Jaakkola did you got solution for this? Can you get the link local IPv6 address now from android device?

Comment: Nope. I did research to understand why it happened but never found clear answer for it. I guess protocol-wise there is no reason and the behaviour must be related to overall address allocation/conventions. Thanks @NickCardoso fixing my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in minimum having SLAAC enabled (with some valid IPv6 network broadcasted) will enabled Android to use link-local addresses.

The address does not need to go anywhere but you will want to be careful with this as Android 7 changed the behaviour so that it will assume IPv6 as the primary if it received it first - meaning if the IPv6 address is not valid things get stuck.

In Android 6, the device would make IPv4 the primary immediately when it receives the address.

Comment: @Nice Cardoso.. How to get the Link local IPv6 address from android device?